# SocketException: Socket closed only with motorola moto g 2013

Tags: android, sockets, android-5.0-lollipop, socketexception

I am having an issue with my Moto G 2013 version. I have an application that is perfectly working on many different devices but on a Motorola Moto G 2013:

```
05-18 22:54:40.329      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
05-18 22:54:40.346      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.net.DatagramSocket.checkOpen(DatagramSocket.java:440)
05-18 22:54:40.346      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:286)
05-18 22:54:40.346      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at com.samsung.multiscreen.net.ssdp.SSDPSearch$2.run(SSDPSearch.java:140)
05-18 22:54:40.349      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
05-18 22:54:40.349      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:279)
05-18 22:54:40.349      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
05-18 22:54:40.349      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
05-18 22:54:40.349      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-18 22:54:40.349      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-18 22:54:40.350      425-547/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am running the application on a Samsung S5 (Lollipop), a Samsung Galaxy Tab S (KitKat), a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (JellyBean), a BQ E5 (KitKat)... And it is always the same version of the application.
The Moto G has Lollipop and I have no clue where the issue is. First I thought it was because of the Android version but after testing it with the S5 I have no idea. They all have the same configuration (developer options) with USB debug enabled, etc.

Thanks for your suggestions

edit:
I am using the SDK of samsung multi screen, so I am using libraries already made and tested. (http://multiscreen.samsung.com/documentation.html)

The exception appears when running this code, which is the first one to use "internet":

```
public void findDevice(){
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Device.search(new DeviceAsyncResult<List<Device>>() {
                    public void onResult(final List<Device> devices) {
                        deviceList = devices;
                    }

                    public void onError(final DeviceError error) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: Is that the only message about the error you get? There must be more information and some **code** would be useful.

Comment: This is an incomplete error message - not even the process ID is showing, so at this point it is unproven that it even relates to your app.  You need to provide a far more complete error message, and the code involved therein if you want help.

Comment: sorry, just updated. Let me know if you need anything else :) and thanks for your fast answers

Comment: @user4467097 Code of source files mentioned would be very useful.